# Regular expressions string replacement

Tags: regex, pentaho-spoon

I need a little help with regular expressions. I need to locate a string:

> {"users":[

and replace it with

> {"name": "blaaaa", "users":[

In a complex json file.

I am completely ignorant about regexes.

Thank you

Comment: any attempts?..

Comment: If you want to handle actual JSON cases - don't do it with regexes, use a parser. If you don't - there is nothing regexy about this case, simply replace `'"users"'` with `'"name": "blaaaa", "users"'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex for JSON, or any other format that requires a parser, is not a good idea. Parse it using your favorite parser, add `name` attribute, and serialize the results back to JSON.

If you would like to continue with a regex exercise, however, here is how you can do it: one simple approach is to search for the `{` preceding `"users"`, and then replace it with `{"name":"blaaaa",` text. The "followed by" concept is expressed with the look-ahead construct `(?=<text>)`:

```
{(?="users":\[)
```

Note the escape symbol `\` in front of `[`, which is necessary because `[` is part of regex syntax.

Comment: And now add support for strings containing the same... xd

Comment: @ndn C'mon, you know it never happens! I mean, what normal string would have JSON fragments in it, right??? ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: Thank for quick response. I got n error saying: Illegal repetition: {(?="users":\[)

Comment: @SrdjanNikitovic What program gave you the error? Did you forget to include the slash?

Comment: You'll be surprised. I've seen an XML API that consisted of a single string containing JSON. Maybe if they decide to support JSON in the future as well... xd xd xd

Comment: Pentahoo Spoon, I am doing an ETL job. I put the Search term to be
 "{(?="users":\[)"

Comment: @SrdjanNikitovic You need a backslash in front of the square bracket.

Comment: Ah yes, I have it. I do not know when I copy it here itdisaperas.

Comment: @SrdjanNikitovic I am not familiar with Pentahoo Spoon. Check their regex documentation, and try simpler things, e.g. looking for `users` with no quotes, then `"users"` with quotes, then for `{`, and so on. At some point you will detect what symbol is causing the problem, which will let you address the issue. If regex does not work, a plain text replacement is sufficient in this situation, too: searching and replacing what you have in the question should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Regular text search doesnt work :)